# Git Clone Error fatal: index-pack failed fatal: error in sideband demultiplexer

Tags: git, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a git repository residing at remote windows server 2008 machine and i'm running the following daemon command to share the repository 
 **git daemon --base-path='/d/test/' --export-all --reuseaddr --informative-errors --verbose**

But i'm able to clone the repository from windows 7 machine once and thereafter if i try to clone the repository its throwing me the errors
fatal: index-pack failed
fatal: error in sideband demultiplexer

Using the below command to clone the repository:
**git clone git://RemoteIPAddress/repository**

I'm also able to clone the repository within the windows server machine with the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to a newer `git daemon` should resolve this issue. It did for me.